# Android. Change margin of LinearLayout on runtime

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, margin

I am trying to move a LinearLayout view by modifying it's margins using an interface and following code:

```
        @Override
public void onListScroll(int offset) {
        tabBarOffset += offset;
        if (tabBarOffset < 0) tabBarOffset = 0;
        if (tabBarOffset > 50) tabBarOffset = 50;
        View tabBar = findViewById(R.id.movingTabBar);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tabBar.getLayoutParams();
        params.topMargin = tabBarOffset;
    }
```

the code works with the first call -- when the activity is created. But whenever the code block is called after, no changes in the view are being happened. I can confirm that the margin parameter is trully being changed, because of three facts : 
1) the code works on start up
2) logging the marginTop value always gives new values ( it is being changed)
3) in the Hierarchy View i could see the new margin value

so i am thinking i just have to call some method to update the view itself? to make it redraw?
or may be i have to call some code on the UI thread? because this code is being run from interface callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onListScroll(final int offset) {

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabBarOffset += offset;
            if (tabBarOffset < 0) tabBarOffset = 0;
            if (tabBarOffset > 50) tabBarOffset = 50;
            ViewGroup tabBar = findViewById(R.id.movingTabBar);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) tabBar.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = tabBarOffset;
            tabBar.requestLayout();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. Sadly, this has no effect.

Comment: just for the sake of the interest, please try the edited variant

Comment: although it works, the calculations turn out to be not cheap. I guess i will have to use simpe TranslateY and TranslatY at the end of the day. Trying to implement the scrollview with moving topBar. Will mark the answer as correct anyway. Thanks.